# Remove spaces and convert values to as numeric when only numbers in R

Tags: r, dplyr, number-formatting

I've been looking in the web for this problem

The thing different from usual findings is that I have columns where I have numbers and other values different from plain numbers.

Say for example:

```
df <- data.frame('Col1' = c('421', ' 0.52', '-0.88 ', '1.2 (ref)', ' 97  '),
                 'Col2' = c('0.0', '0.27,0.91', '3.0', ' 10242.3', '  94.5'))
```

I would like to remove spaces from the cells only composed by numbers. Not sure if, for example, `0.52`, that `dot` character makes it still be considered as number. Also in `-0.88` the `-` character.

So far I would use

```
library(stringr)
# Remove spaces
df$Col1 <- str_replace_all(df$Col1, "\\s+", "")

library(dplyr)
# Convert to as.numeric
df %>%
mutate_all(funs(as.numeric(as.character(.)))
```

But I would not like to just replace every single space, for example in the value `1.2 (ref)`, I would like to keep that space. Also, not to change every value to as.numeric, only where pure numbers, or `\d+\.\d+`, or `\-\d+\.\d+`  (regex)

Also if I attempt to convert to `as.numeric`, the numeric values somehow change drastically, I understand this is because of the spaces present in the values.

Thanks in advance

Comment: In addition to spaces, you have other characters like `(ref)` which are not numeric

Comment: If you want to keep values such as `1.2 (ref)`, then _all_ values in the column will be coerced to `character`, no matter how "numeric" they appear - a column can only have a _single class_. Anyway, for leading / trailing spaces in general, see the `strip.white` argument in `read.table`.

Comment: Do you mean to say that you want to remove spaces from `-0.88 ` but not from `'1.2 (ref)'` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I built a function using a `regex`

```
library(tidyverse)
mClean <- function(strVec){
  pass1 <- strVec %>% 
    str_trim() %>% 
    str_extract("(?x)        # Perl-style whitespace
                ^[\\+\\-]?   # An optional leading +/-
                \\d+         # the integer part
                (\\.\\d+)? # A fractional part
                ") %>% 
    as.numeric()
}
```

I put your data in a tibble and ran it:

```
df <- tibble('Col1' = c('421', ' 0.52', '-0.88 ', '1.2 (ref)', ' 97  '),
                 'Col2' = c('0.0', '0.27,0.91', '3.0', ' 10242.3', '  94.5')) %>% 
  mutate(cln1 = as.numeric(mClean(Col1)),
         cln2 = as.numeric(mClean(Col2)))
df

# A tibble: 5 x 4
  Col1      Col2          cln1     cln2
  <chr>     <chr>        <dbl>    <dbl>
1 421       0.0         421        0   
2 " 0.52"   0.27,0.91     0.52     0.27
3 "-0.88 "  3.0          -0.88     3   
4 1.2 (ref) " 10242.3"    1.2  10242.  
5 " 97  "   "  94.5"     97       94.5
```

I wasn't sure what you wanted done with that '0.27,0.91'.  Break it into two rows?  Make another column for the '0.91'? Anyway, this keeps the original input in the same row as the cleaned up values.

Answer (score 2):

You have several issues as pointed out by `akrun` and `Henrik`: as columns in a data frame can only be of the same class, the `1.2(ref)` value forces the column to be of class `character`. Also, in `Col2` there is this entry: `0.27,0.91`. This looks like two values and you need to decide how to deal with this.

Suggestions: split `Col1` into two columns. One column holds the numeric values and the other holds the value `ref` or `NA`. This can be a character or factor column. As for the double numeric value: split into two columns or decided which value you would like to retain.

Under these assumptions your code could be something like this (using the `tidyverse` approach):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

df <- data.frame('Col1' = c('421', ' 0.52', '-0.88 ', '1.2 (ref)', ' 97  '),
                 'Col2' = c('0.0', '0.27,0.91', '3.0', ' 10242.3', '  94.5'))

df <- df %>%
  mutate_all(.funs = funs(str_trim)) %>% # remove leading and trailing spaces
  separate(col = Col1, into = c("Value_1", "Reference"), sep = "\\s|,") %>% # split into 2 columns at comma or space
  separate(col = Col2, into = c("Value_2", "Value_3"), sep = "\\s|,") %>% # split into 2 columns at comma or space
  mutate_at(.vars = vars(starts_with("Value")), as.numeric) #convert character to numeric
```

This code does not scale well: if your dataset would have many columns and each column requires to be split in a different way things would get complicated. Better to review your dataset first and do some quality control on it. If any column can contains comma separated values: you can write code to catch that and apply a correction in uniform way. Combinations of values and text is something you should not allow in your dataset.

Output:

```
> glimpse(df)
Observations: 5
Variables: 4
$ Value_1   <dbl> 421.00, 0.52, -0.88, 1.20, 97.00
$ Reference <chr> NA, NA, NA, "(ref)", NA
$ Value_2   <dbl> 0.00, 0.27, 3.00, 10242.30, 94.50
$ Value_3   <dbl> NA, 0.91, NA, NA, NA

> df
  Value_1 Reference  Value_2 Value_3
1  421.00      <NA>     0.00      NA
2    0.52      <NA>     0.27    0.91
3   -0.88      <NA>     3.00      NA
4    1.20     (ref) 10242.30      NA
5   97.00      <NA>    94.50      NA
```